# Error message during booting up Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, dmesg

I got the following error message on booting up.

```
systemd-udevd[368]: '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/var/run/alsa restore 0' 
[672] terminated by signal 81 (Unknown signal 81)
```

What does it mean and how do I resolve it? (I could successfully log in and the machine auto shutdown after sometime)

Comment: What have you already tried - have you done basics like "sudo apt-get upgrade" after login or checked for broken pakages "sudo apt-get -f install" or "sudo dpkg --configure -a"

Comment: @DnrDevil No bcause I wanted to know about the specific cause behind this.